# lua 5.2.1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, windows, lua

I'm using visual studio 2012 and when I try to compile, I get following errors:

```
Error   7   error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals   C:\Users\MS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LuaTest\Release\LuaTest.exe   LuaTest
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_close    C:\Users\MS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LuaTest\LuaTest\main.obj  LuaTest
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pcallk   C:\Users\MS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LuaTest\LuaTest\main.obj  LuaTest
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop   C:\Users\MS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LuaTest\LuaTest\main.obj  LuaTest
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_loadfilex   C:\Users\MS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LuaTest\LuaTest\main.obj  LuaTest
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate C:\Users\MS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LuaTest\LuaTest\main.obj LuaTest
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaopen_base C:\Users\MS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LuaTest\LuaTest\main.obj  LuaTest
```

Source code taken from
[HERE](http://blog.acamara.es/2012/08/14/running-a-lua-5-2-script-from-c/).

Using following library version: [lua-5.2.1_Win32_dll10_lib.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2.1/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/)

I tried different lua52.lib files, but with all of them I get these errors.
What could be wrong?

Comment: The linker says 6 unresolved symbols, but I only see 4. Are the 2 other `luaL_newstate` and `luaL_openlibs`? The background question I am asking: do these unresolved symbols represent _all_ the Lua functions you are using in the application or only _some_ ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I edited my original post. One unresolved symbol is indeed luaL_newstate, but the other is _luaopen_base.

Comment: These 6 unresolved symbols represent indeed _all_ the Lua functions used in the simple tutorial example. This implies that no Lua 5.2 library is used by the linker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Visual Studio 2012, but library files [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2.1/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/) appealingly only support up to Visual Studio 2010.

Anyway, Lua is small and very easy to compile. I would really recommend you to include Lua [source files](http://www.lua.org/ftp/) in Visual Studio instead of libraries.